# mariadb won't start

Tags: mariadb, mysqld

Using Vultr with Ubuntu 16.04 i386 along with EasyEngine and WP-CLI installed.

Today I updated the machine to Ubuntu 16.04.3 LTS and upon restart the MySQL stopped working.

I tried several ways and gathered that when I do `service mysql status` --

```
    ● mariadb.service - MariaDB database server
   Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/mariadb.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
  Drop-In: /etc/systemd/system/mariadb.service.d
           └─migrated-from-my.cnf-settings.conf
   Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Thu 2017-12-21 13:55:59 UTC; 42min ago
  Process: 2931 ExecStart=/usr/sbin/mysqld $MYSQLD_OPTS $_WSREP_NEW_CLUSTER $_WSREP_START_POSITION (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)
  Process: 2774 ExecStartPre=/bin/sh -c [ ! -e /usr/bin/galera_recovery ] && VAR= ||   VAR=`/usr/bin/galera_recovery`; [ $? -eq 0 ]   && systemctl set-environment _WSREP_START_POSITION=
  Process: 2767 ExecStartPre=/bin/sh -c systemctl unset-environment _WSREP_START_POSITION (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
  Process: 2761 ExecStartPre=/usr/bin/install -m 755 -o mysql -g root -d /var/run/mysqld (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
 Main PID: 2931 (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)
   Status: "MariaDB server is down"

Dec 21 13:55:58 mstockserver systemd[1]: Starting MariaDB database server...
Dec 21 13:55:59 mstockserver mysqld[2931]: 2017-12-21 13:55:59 3069110272 [Note] /usr/sbin/mysqld (mysqld 10.1.29-MariaDB-1~xenial) starting as process 2931 ...
Dec 21 13:55:59 mstockserver mysqld[2931]: 2017-12-21 13:55:59 3069110272 [Warning] Can't create test file /var/lib/mysql/mstockserver.lower-test
Dec 21 13:55:59 mstockserver mysqld[2931]: 2017-12-21 13:55:59 3069110272 [ERROR] mysqld: File '/var/log/mysql/mariadb-bin.index' not found (Errcode: 13 "Permission denied")
Dec 21 13:55:59 mstockserver mysqld[2931]: 2017-12-21 13:55:59 3069110272 [ERROR] Aborting
Dec 21 13:55:59 mstockserver systemd[1]: mariadb.service: Main process exited, code=exited, status=1/FAILURE
Dec 21 13:55:59 mstockserver systemd[1]: Failed to start MariaDB database server.
Dec 21 13:55:59 mstockserver systemd[1]: mariadb.service: Unit entered failed state.
Dec 21 13:55:59 mstockserver systemd[1]: mariadb.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
```

I tried doing EasyEngine's `ee stack install --mysql` too but it also returns --

```
Adding repository for MySQL, please wait...
Updating apt-cache, please wait...
Installing packages, please wait...
Downloading MySQLTuner           [Done]
Reload : mysql     [Failed]
Successfully installed packages
```

Also, the `df` return --

```
Filesystem     1K-blocks    Used Available Use% Mounted on
udev              493416       0    493416   0% /dev
tmpfs             102392    4500     97892   5% /run
/dev/vda1       25745836 3370420  21048392  14% /
tmpfs             511948       0    511948   0% /dev/shm
tmpfs               5120       0      5120   0% /run/lock
tmpfs             511948       0    511948   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
tmpfs             102392       0    102392   0% /run/user/0
```

I have a much needed DB on the MySQL side. Can you advice anything?

Comment: I don't know what went wrong but that `ee stack install --mysql` attempt to fix doesn't seem right. It seems you had MariaDB, not vanilla MySQL installed.

Comment: @yper-trollᵀᴹ I was trying everything. Any advice?

Comment: Start by checking the error logs (probably at `/var/log/mysql/`)

Comment: Also: we can't see the full line of the error: `[ERROR] mysqld: File '/var/log/mysql/mariadb-bin.i` ...)

Comment: In the folder you mentioned there is only -- mariadb-bin.000002  mariadb-bin.000003  mariadb-bin.000004  mariadb-bin.index

Comment: Check in `/var/log/` as well. If they aren't there, then try to locate `my.cnf` that was being used (you may have more than one in the system)

Comment: I updated the error message in the question

Comment: /var/log -- mysql.log is empty

Comment: No other error log there? It might be named differently. Check if there is a `/etc/mysql/my.cnf` for the config file. It should tell you where the error log location is.

Comment: "Permission denied" -- who were you logged in as when you did the install?

Comment: @RickJames as the root